# Selecting top 3 artist by country with respect to revenue in SQLITE 3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have multiple table which are artists, albums, tracks, invoice_items, invoices,  customers.

I wrote below sql query :

```
select country, artistid, name, revenue from 
(select t6.country, t1.artistid, t1.name, sum(t4.quantity*t4.unitprice) as revenue 
from artists 
t1 inner join albums t2 
inner join tracks t3 
inner join invoice_items t4 
inner join invoices t5 
inner join customers t6 on t1.artistid=t2.artistid 
and t2.albumid=t3.albumid 
and t3.trackid=t4.trackid 
and t4.invoiceid=t5.invoiceid 
and t5.customerid=t6.customerid 
group by t6.country, t1.artistid 
);
```

Output from query:

[image: Output]

Expected Output:
Top 3 artist sort by revenue for each country. As I need to get top 3 artist for argentina, australia, brazil, usa respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery to identify the top 5 revenue earners per country.  You may place your current query into a resuable CTE for convenience:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT t6.country, t1.artistid, t1.name, SUM(t4.quantity*t4.unitprice) AS revenue
    FROM artists t1
    INNER JOIN albums t2 ON t1.artistid = t2.artistid
    INNER JOIN tracks t3 ON t2.albumid = t3.albumid
    INNER JOIN invoice_items t4 ON t3.trackid = t4.trackid
    INNER JOIN invoices t5 ON t4.invoiceid = t5.invoiceid
    INNER JOIN customers t6 ON t5.customerid = t6.customerid
    GROUP BY t6.country, t1.artistid, t1.name
)

SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE artistid IN (
    SELECT t2.artistid
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t1.country = t2.country
    ORDER BY t2.revenue DESC, t2.name
    LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY
    country, revenue DESC;
```

### Demo

Note that I added an order level by name in the `LIMIT` subquery.  This is to explicitly break a tie should two or more artists happen to have the same revenue for a given country.  In this case, the alphabetically earlier name(s) is the one which would be shown first.

Comment: How am i supposed to  store the output from my first query as some table? if i do not store it as a table, this logic will not work.

Comment: @Nick See my updated answer.  You may place your query into a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Use the rank function:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT ARTISTID,
               NAME,
               COUNTRY,
               REVENUE,
               RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY COUNTRY ORDER BY REVENUE DESC) RANK
          FROM ARTISTS)
 WHERE RANK < 4
```

https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html